# Condition for a curve to bound disks on the surface of a handlebody

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $\Sigma$ be a closed orientable surface of genus $g$ and let $\alpha = \{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_g\}$ be a set of pairwise nonintertersecting nonseparating simple closed curves on $\Sigma$.  Then $\alpha$ determines a way of identifying the boundary of a genus $g$ handlebody $H$ with $\Sigma$.  If $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve in $\Sigma$ that does not intersect any of the $\alpha_i$, does it follow that $\gamma$ will bound a properly embedded disk when we identify $\Sigma$ with $\partial H$?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. The curves $\alpha_j$ can be contractible? Further, if you have $\alpha_1$, a nontrivial circle on a torus, and $\gamma$ be just close to $\alpha_1$, going "paralelly", then $\gamma$ doesn't bound any disc...

Comment: Whoops - forgot to say nonseparating. Parallel is fine - those will bound disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably assumed that the curves are also pairwise non-isotopic (since otherwise (1) the curves do not determine the handlebody attachment uniquely and (2) the answer would be "no" since you could take $g$ parallel copies of the same nonseparating curve in a genus-$g$ surface, and for $g>1$, given any handlebody attachment there are plenty of disjoint curves that don't bound disks).

Identify $\Sigma$ with $\partial H$, and let $D_1,\dots,D_g\subset H$ be a system of disjoint disks such that $\partial D_i=\alpha_i$ for each $i$.  If $\gamma$ does not intersect any of the $\alpha_i$, then $\gamma$ is an embedded loop in the boundary of $B=H-\bigcup_i \nu(D_i)$.  Since $B$ is a ball, $\gamma$ bounds a disk $D\subset B$, which is also a disk in $H$.